# Por que essa pergunta não foi fechada, mesmo aparentemente com votos o suficiente pelas filas de análise?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, fechamento

Analisando o [histórico de revisão desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/523894/timeline) vejo que ela foi para duas filas de análise:

- [Publicações de Baixa Qualidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/345797): três análises, todas "Fechar" - 2 votos de usuários 3k+ de reputação e 1 com reputação insuficiente.
- [Votos para Fechar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/345836): uma análise "Fechar", por um usuário diferente.

Vendo isso eu interpreto que houve (ao menos) três votos de fechamento no período entre 21/08 e 09/09. Entretanto, a pergunta encontra-se aberta e sem um evento de reabertura no histórico de revisão:

[image: Histórico de revisão da pergunta mostrando que as votações nas filas foram invalidadas.]

Ou seja, a pergunta não foi fechada e as análises foram "invalidadas". O que houve por aqui? Os votos não atingiram a quantidade mínima (3)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi vendo todo histórico os votos de fechamento foram expirados, então eles não foram considerados.

Os votos não duram para sempre (eu achei algo de 14 dias, mas é condicional com outros fatores, e vi informações diferentes em outros lugares, é confuso, não dá para cravar como o algoritmo está, mas expira). O que vale é voto, não análise.

A análise foi invalidada por alguma ação posterior que tornou-as sem efeito.

Comment: @RafaelTavares A regra de expiração dos votos está [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902/401803) (o FAQ oficial linka pra esse post, então deve ser a regra atual). Como a pergunta tem menos de 100 visualizações, cai na primeira regra: "*votes expire one per day after 14 days*"

Comment: Ah, certo. Muito provavelmente foi isso mesmo então, obrigado aos dois. Eu achava (com base em nada) que expiravam em 21 dias.